# File seek operation is missing out bytes randomly while writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the process of porting code from python2 to python3. The code below in python2 is working fine for python3, except on the occasions where it is over writing a couple of bytes at the end from the previous line while writing a new packet to the file. This is causing an error rate of 10% while reading out the packets from the file (The error rate was around 2% in python2).

```
logfile = open(filepath, 'w+')

# Gets the offset to write to the file (EOF)
offset = self.enddict[fname]

# The output message 
outmsg = "%ld\n%d\n%s\n" % (now, msg_len, msg)

#Seeks to the given offset and writes the message out
logfile.seek(offset)
logfile.write(outmsg)
```

I've tried out a couple of solutions to resolve this issue, but haven't got the right one so far:

1. Add extra new lines to the beginning and end of the output message. This seems to mitigate the issue (reduces the error rate to 2%), but it doesn't seem like a viable solution as we'd need to change various readers that are reading off the file downstream.

```
outmsg = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%ld\n%d\n%s\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" % (now, msg_len, msg)
```

2. Use io.SEEK_END. This seems to write the packets correctly to the file and the error rate drops close to 0 %. But, it's messing up with the offsets written to the DB. While reading the chunk from the file by using the offsets in the DB, we're getting corrupted chunk.

```
logfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
```

3. I did some research into using os.lseek and found it to be slower than seek.

Comment: Files aren't line-oriented; unless the line you are writing is *exactly* the same size as the old line, you will overwrite the beginning of the next line (or leave the end of the old line in place).

Comment: Using `seek()` on text files is problematic not only because lines are usually of varying lengths, but also because the line endings might get translated from multi- to single characters when they are read.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, is there a way around this ?

Comment: @martineau, The existing python2.7 works with seek(start) . What is the equivalent method in Python 3.7 ?

Comment: Alok: I don't think it's specific to Python 2 or 3 — the same potential problem exists in both. The fact that a couple of bytes are being overwritten is a strong indicator that this issue is the cause. I don't know why you haven't encountered (or noticed) it in Python 2.

Comment: If you [edit] your question and added a [mre], it would be helpful.

Comment: @martineau, We did encounter about 2% packet losses on python 2, but the losses seems to have gone up to 10% in python 3.

Comment: Ahh, so your claim that the code worked fine in python2 isn't quite true. In the snippet of code currently in your question you're only seeking to the end of the file. If all you want to do is write to the end of the file, just `open()` in it in append mode (i.e. `open(filepath, 'a')`). See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), then you won't need to call `seek()` at all. (In fact you may not need the `offset` value at all.)

Comment: @martineau, Thanks for the suggestion. But the append option is working fine while writing the packets to the file. But we'd still be needing the offset to be maintained in an internal cache, as we're storing these values in the database, to be used by down stream readers to read off the file using these values. 
I tried out the option, but the offsets seems to be getting messed up in the database for some reason.
I also tried the self.logfile.tell() option to get the start of the offset from the end of the file and then use self.logfile.seek(offset). It didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not surprised you're still having problems if you're still trying to use `tell()` and `seek()` on the text file (for other purposes). One possible workaround might be to use a line-count instead of a byte-offset. This will make going to a specific location (line number) in the file much slower, however.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution seems to be getting rid of the missing bytes issue during seek operation:

```
self.logfile.seek(offset)
off_bytes_count = len(self.logfile.read())
if off_bytes_count:
    offset += off_bytes_count
    self.logfile.seek(offset)
```

Here, the off_bytes_count is the count of the bytes that’s remaining after the seek operation.